# linking an INSERT statement to a value of a non key column in another

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I have a database with these tables:

[image: Table Relationships]

I'm inserting the values ProjName, Description and FileStorage into the table `Project`. I am trying to link this information to the table `Users`, where I posses only the value of the non-key column AUID. So far I have something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Project (ProjName, Description, FileStorage)
VALUES 
(
   '#form.capstoneName#'
   ,'#form.capstoneDescription#'
   , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_blob" value="#FileReadBinary(FORM.capstoneFile)#"> 
)
```

However, I want this specific INSERT statement to be related to the ID column of the Users table through the value AUID which I'm storing for the logged in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Project `ID` is an identity column, use the [cfquery result attribute](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfquery.html) with the INSERT query to obtain the newly generated Project `ID`. Then use an INSERT/SELECT to lookup the corresponding User ID and insert both values into the `Project_Users` table. Modify the [cfqueryparam](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfqueryparam.html) cfsqltypes as needed.

```
  <!--- Inserts one record for EACH matching AUID value --->
  INSERT INTO Project_Users ( ProjectID, UserID )
  SELECT <cfqueryparam value="#resultName.generatedKey#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
        , ID
  FROM   Users
  WHERE  AUID = <cfqueryparam value="{The_AUID_Value}" cfsqltype="{Update_With_Your_Type}">
```

**NB:** Be sure to wrap both INSERT's in a [cftransaction](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-t/cftransaction.html), to ensure both queries either [succeed or fail as a single unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction).

See additional examples of "result" attribute:

- [How to get ID (PK) of newly created record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739220/how-to-get-id-pk-of-newly-created-record)
- [Coldfusion: Can't reference var from query result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719607/coldfusion-cant-reference-var-from-query-result-set)

Comment: I will give this a try. Shoutout, thanks for helping me understand many to many

Comment: You are welcome. One thing I forgot to mention, be sure to wrap both of the INSERT's in a `cftransaction`. That ensures you do not end up with inconsistent data if one of the INSERT's fails for some reason.